# help with array for last field in php or codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, forms, codeigniter

I have been on this for a day now and still cant solve it though it should be quite simple. I have a php code.

```
    foreach($cart as $line=>$item)
{
    echo form_open("sales/edit_item/$line");
?>


    <td style="align:center;"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>



    <?php if ($items_module_allowed)
    {
    ?>
        <td><?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$item['price'],'size'=>'6'));?></td>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
        <?php echo form_hidden('price',$item['price']); ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <td>
    <?php
        if($item['is_serialized']==1)
        {
            echo $item['quantity'];
            echo form_hidden('quantity',$item['quantity']);
        }
        else
        {
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'quantity','value'=>$item['quantity'],'size'=>'2'));
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    </div></div>

    <td><?php echo to_currency($item['price']*$item['quantity']-$item['price']*$item['quantity']*$item['discount']/100); ?></td>

    <?php
        if($item['allow_alt_description']==1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            if ($item['description']!='')
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="color:#2F4F4F";>
    <?php
        if($item['is_serialized']==1)
        {
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td colspan=3 style="text-align:left;">
    <?php
        if($item['is_serialized']==1)
        {
        }
    ?>
    </td>


    </tr>
    <tr style="height:3px">
    <td colspan=8 style="background-color:white"> </td>
    </tr>       </form>
<?php
}
```

}
?>

This creates fields with relevant data and works ok. I just need to get the last field and echo it, I have tried everything and it still loops through the array, or does not work. This might be simple to someone else but it has confused me for a day now.

Comment: You just want to get the last value in array? like `$cart[count($cart)-1]`? Or use [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function.

Comment: Do you just want the last item in `$cart`, or do you want to loop through and only echo something on the last item?

Comment: I dont think it is the $cart. I think what i need is the last $line value. It outputs as form_open("sales/edit_item/{$lastLine}, ie form_open("sales/edit_item/1 ,2 ,3 ,etc. I think maybe that has been the problem. Any ideas.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a loop, such as `for` or `foreach` or `while`, it will iterate over every single child element of the array until it reaches the end. You don't need to loop, you simply need to access the last member of the array, like so:

```
$lastLine = end( array_keys($cart) );
echo form_open("sales/edit_item/{$lastLine}");
```

**Edit:** Now that I understand a bit better:

```
$lastItem = array_slice($cart, -1, null, true);
$line = key($lastItem);
$item = reset($lastItem);
echo form_open("sales/edit_item/{$line}");
?>
<!-- do all your html-ish stuff here. -->
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have tried this but it seems that unless I have the loop in I dont seem to get any fields populated. They are zero or empty. I have a bit more code I pasted below. Am I missing something stupid. I am a complete noob to php. many thanks.

Comment: Based on the code in your original post, that doesn't really make much sense. You're not setting any part of the array in the loop. Where did you paste the extra code?

Comment: I am not sure if it let me paste . I will try again. Thanks Michael. $lastLine = end( array_keys($cart) );
echo form_open("sales/edit_item/{$lastLine}");

  
  <td style="align:center;"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>



  <?php if ($items_module_allowed)
  {
  ?>
   <td><?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$item['price'],'size'=>'6'));?></td>
  <?php
  }
  else
  {
  ?>
   <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
   <?php echo form_hidden('price',$item['price']); ?>

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I was very confused by your question, but now I understand it a bit better. See my updated post.

Comment: Hi michael. Still no joy, but bit further. It seems to echo one item but the wrong one. And then it repeats, the item if I run it again. Dont know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Hi Michael, still no joy. I think though that everything is ordered not by cart but by line. ie form_open("sales/edit_item/{$lastLine} opens form_open("sales/edit_item/1,2,3 etc. I think maybe that is the problem. I would need the last element of this loop. Its driving me crazy lol. Does that make any more sense. I can post more code but it seems to limit me to how much I can paste.

Comment: Hi Michael, managed to paste it all. Would be pleased if you could take a look and advise. many thanks.

Comment: That's not including your implementation of what I'm trying to get you to do. That's what I need to see.